# How to check if webpage is opened from mail link?

Tags: html, referrer

I need to check if a web page is opened by clicking on link in registration email sent to registered visitor. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: yes. just append a parameter in the querystring of the link you have to send. then read it (via server side scripting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like thomas said, append a parameter to the url
http://www.mypage.com/registration.php?usrid=121542